# Should I have 2 lists in this C# program or just 1?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have this code and it's about a Roller Coaster, the game has a capacity of 5 people and its duration is about 10 seconds... Every 3 seconds the Park class creates people and add it to a List which is like a queue for the game but what I need it to do is for the people to enter the game as soon as a place is available in the game. The game starts when its full so the first 5 people should get directly into the game and not join the queue. So should I have one list for the queue and another one for the game? What can I modify here to do that and also to tell the user which person got into the game?

```
class RollerCoaster
{
    private Chronometer crono;
    private List<Person> Queue; //Queue
    private int nMax;
    private Output output;
    private int duration; //Game duration
    private UI ui;

    public RollerCoaster(int n)
    {
        ui = new UI();
        crono = new Chronometer();
        Queue = new List<Person>();
        this.nMax = n;
        duration = 10; 
        output = ui.output;

        crono.Start(1000);

        crono.AddAction(Verify);
    }

    public void AddPerson(Person p)
    {
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        Queue.Add(p);

        output("Person " + p.id + " joined the queue at " + date);   
    }

    public void RemovePersons()
    {
        crono.RemoveAction(DecreaseTime);

        duration = 10;

        output("The ride just ended!");

        output("People got down at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public void Verify()
    {
        if (Queue.Count == this.nMax)
        {
            output("Roller Coaster is finally full!. Starting ride at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Queue = new List<Person>();
            crono.AddAction(DecreaseTime);   
        }
    }

    public void DecreaseTime()
    {
        duration--;
        if (duration == 0)
        {
            RemovePersons();
        }
    }
}
```

The current output of this code is:

> Person 1 joined the queue at 9/4/2017 8:58:21 AM
>
> Person 2 joined the queue at 9/4/2017 8:58:24 AM
>
> Person 3 joined the queue at 9/4/2017 8:58:27 AM
>
> Person 4 joined the queue at 9/4/2017 8:58:30 AM
>
> Person 5 joined the queue at 9/4/2017 8:58:33 AM
>
> Roller Coaster is finally full!. Starting ride at 9/4/2017 8:58:34 AM
>
> Person 6 joined the queue at 9/4/2017 8:58:36 AM
>
> Person 7 joined the queue at 9/4/2017 8:58:39 AM
>
> Person 8 joined the queue at 9/4/2017 8:58:42 AM
>
> The ride just ended! People got down at 9/4/2017 8:58:44 AM
>
> Person 9 joined the queue at 9/4/2017 8:58:45 AM
>
> Person 10 joined the queue at 9/4/2017 8:58:48 AM
>
> Roller Coaster is finally full!. Starting ride at 9/4/2017 8:58:49 AM

Comment: This sounds like you want a review, maybe go here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would use a `Queue<>` for the, well, queue of the users who are waiting and a `List<>` for the people in game

Comment: Instead of `Queue = new List<Person>();` I would say `Queue.Clear();` Also, field names usually start with a lowercase letter.